# Access individual pixels in CBitmap object

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, gdi

As an exercise, I am attempting to write a piece of code which can sample a single pixel from an MFC CBitmap object, at a particular x/y location.

The class does not have any `GetPixel` type interface, and most of the information I have seen indicates copying the entire contents of the CBitmap bits via `CBitmap::GetBitMapBits`, which seems extremely inefficient.

Is there no way to gain access to the byte array via pointer and access it as an array?

Comment: `GetPixel` is *extremely* inefficient. The most efficient way to do this is indeed to get all the bits, manipulate the one(s) you want, and then copy them back. I know, it sounds weird, but that's just how bitmaps work, unless you have a device-independent bitmap (DIB).

Comment: What about using `CImage` instead of `CBitmap` and do `BYTE* ptr = (BYTE*)image.GetPixelAddress(x, y);` ? You will get the RGB values on `ptr[0]`,  `ptr[1]`, `ptr[2]` if the bitmap consists of a 24 bit format!

Comment: @CodyGray: Calling `GetPixel` on a memory device context is likely the most efficient way to sample a *"single pixel"*, as requested in this question.

Comment: @IInspectable:And the cost of creating the memory context? I don't know how much it is. My answer coincides with yours on the time it as posted and also on the used approach.

Comment: @sergiol The cost of creating the memory context is largely irrelevant, as you can create it when you start the application and re-use it.

Comment: @sergiol: The cost of creating a memory device context is fairly low. It's essentially just a structure with some properties (viewport, scaling, etc.) and painting resources (pen, brush, etc.). The potentially largest resource is the backing bitmap. When creating a memory device context, however, the bitmap that is created is a monochrome bitmap of size 1x1. The expensive call is `GetPixel`, in case the device context represents the screen, i.e. it is backed by video memory.

Comment: *"Calling GetPixel on a memory device context is likely the most efficient way to sample a "single pixel", as requested in this question."* It isn't; I've benchmarked it. :-) A DIB is *way* faster, of course, and even if you are forced into using a DDB, writing your own code based around `GetBitmapBits` is somewhat faster, not to mention more generic. Of course, `GetPixel` is *easier*, and less prone to mistakes like resource leaks, if you don't know what you're doing. I don't write code with that consideration in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `CBitmap` object is associated with a [device-independent bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183562(v=vs.85).aspx) (DIB, created by [`CreateDIBSection()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183562(v=vs.85).aspx) for instance), you can get a pointer to directly access the bitmap pixels (without copying) by calling [`GetObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd144904(v=vs.85).aspx). Make sure to call [`GdiFlush()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd144844(v=vs.85).aspx) if you have accessed the bitmap pixels [by any other GDI functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100923-00/?p=12773) before using direct access.

If the `CBitmap` is associated with a [device-dependent bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd183561(v=vs.85).aspx) (DDB, also known as *compatible bitmap*), which method to use depends on how many pixels you want to access.

- If only a **handful of pixels** need to be accessed, you may go the [`CDC::SelectObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhhde73.aspx#cdc__selectobject), [`CDC::GetPixel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhhde73.aspx#cdc__getpixel) route. This will be very slow if you want to read a bigger number of pixel.
- To access a **big number of pixels**, you may use either [`CBitmap::GetBitMapBits()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0022z9(v=vs.120).aspx) or [`GetDIBits()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd144879(v=vs.85).aspx). The latter may be more efficient when you only need to access part of the bitmap pixels because it has parameters to define a range of scanlines to copy.

In either case, a **DDB will always be slower than a DIB** when you need to access it pixel-by-pixel.

The following example detects if a `CBitmap` is associated with either a DIB or a DDB and branches to use the most efficient access method for each case.

```
void DoAwesomeStuff( CBitmap& bitmap )
{
    DIBSECTION dib{ 0 };
    if( ::GetObject( bitmap, sizeof( dib ), &dib ) )
    {
        // GetObject() succeeded so we know that bmp is associated with a DIB.

        // Evaluate the information in dib thoroughly, to determine if you can handle
        // the bitmap format. You will propably restrict yourself to a few uncompressed 
        // formats.
        // In the following example I accept only uncompressed top-down bitmaps 
        // with 32bpp.
        if( dib.dsBmih.biCompression == BI_RGB && 
            dib.dsBmih.biHeight < 0 &&  // negative height indicates top-down bitmap
            dib.dsBmih.biPlanes == 1 && 
            dib.dsBmih.biBitCount == 32 )
        {
            DWORD* pPixels = reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>( dib.dsBm.bmBits );
            // TODO: Access the bitmap directly through the pPixels pointer. 
            // Make sure to check bounds to avoid segfault.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // GetObject() failed because bmp is not a DIB or for some other reason.
        BITMAP bmp{ 0 };
        if( ::GetObject( bitmap, sizeof( bmp ), &bmp ) )
        {
            // GetObject() succeeded so we know that bmp is associated with a DDB.
            CDC dc;
            // Create a memory DC.
            dc.CreateCompatibleDC( nullptr );
            if( CBitmap* pOldBmp = dc.SelectObject( &bitmap ) )
            {
                // Get the bitmap pixel at given coordinates.
                // For accessing a large number of pixels, CBitmap::GetBitMapBits() 
                // or GetDIBits() will be more efficient.
                COLORREF pixel = dc.GetPixel( 42, 24 );

                // Standard cleanup: restore the bitmap that was originally 
                // selected into the DC.
                dc.SelectObject( pOldBmp );
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO: handle error               
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO: handle error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the `CBitmap` into a [CDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhhde73.aspx) ([CDC::SelectObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhhde73.aspx#cdc__selectobject)) first. The device context has a [CDC::GetPixel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhhde73.aspx#cdc__getpixel) member.

Comment: >CodyGray< "GetPixel is extremely inefficient. The most efficient way to do this is indeed to get all the bits, manipulate the one(s) you want, and then copy them back.".... I just fixed a major slow down which called CDC::GetPixel() on each pixel. The solution was to use GetBitmapBits() or device-independent bitmap (DIB) and do your own bit manipulation.

Comment: @diox8tony: The OP wants to *"sample **a single pixel**"*. You solved a different problem, and used a different approach. For this problem, using a memory device context and calling `GetPixel` is the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is **BAD** because the `GetPixel` approach is slow. Didn't delete it, just stroked the text over, only for people coming here to see it is a thing they **SHOULD NOT** do.

<s>Something like</s>

```
CDC mem_dc;
mem_dc.CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
CBitmap* old_bitmap=(CBitmap*)mem_dc.SelectObject(&bmp);

COLORREF cr_xy=mem_dc.GetPixel(x,y);

mem_dc.SelectObject(old_bitmap);
DeleteDC(mem_dc);
```

should do the job.

Comment: Except that it'll be about 100x slower than `GetBitmapBits`

Comment: @Ian Young I think you should time the two approaches and compare the performance.

Comment: @CodyGray: Just made a profile here and discovered a bottleneck cause by `GetPixel`!

Comment: Yes, that is well known. See comments to the question itself. I could have saved you a lot of trouble. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: After the facts, I stroked my answer!